# How to create Multicolumn ListView in Mono for Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

How to create Multicolumn ListView in Mono for Android ?

Waiting for your response.

Comment: Because C# coding is required.

Comment: c# is not the best choice for Android - perhaps for Win 7

Comment: actually I want to use some common WCF service for Android as well as in Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 2):

[This blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160314232324/http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/) should help, since a multicolumn ListView is not a MonoDroid spesific thing.